# Get posts by views AND date

Tags: php, wordpress, arguments

I'm trying to get a list of posts in a widget sorted by views and date ( over the past X number of days). For now I have:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'                => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'               => 'tie_views',
    'posts_per_page'         => $posts_number,
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
);
```

After Querying:

```
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'after' => '1 week ago'
    )
)
```

I get a blank page. So what could be wrong?

I have tried also tried:

```
'date_query' => array(
    'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 days')) 
)
```

Although in WP settings I have "j F Y" for the date format.

But the result is the same, only a blank page comes up. After I remove `date query` everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query'     => array(
        'after' => array(
            'year'  => 2012,
            'month' => 3,
            'day'   => 1,
        ),
    ),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Or with a strtotime()-string:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query'     => array( 'after' => '2012-03-01' ),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```